# How to quicken create pit at level 9 Wizard

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, spellcasting

I am looking for a way to quicken a create pit at level 9. Quicken is +4 and Create Pit is a level 2 spell. So actually I would need to be level 11, is there still a way to quicken Create Pit at level 9 Wizard?
Like with store it in an ring and trigger it or so?

Comment: What options do you have available to accomplish this? Feat choices, background choices, archetype flexibility, retraining from what you have, and/or money?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few items that can achieve that:

- a [Metamagic Rod of Quicken Spell](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicRodsDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Rod%20of%20Metamagic,%20Quickenlesser)
- a [Metamagic Gem of Quicken Spell](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Metamagic%20GemQuickening%20Diamond)
- a [crafted staff](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/Magic-Item-Creation/#Creating_Staves) with a Quickened Create Pit spell inside

Wands cannot be used for that, because wands are limited to 4th-level spell(-slots), but staves can have a 6th-level spell inside them.

Answer (score 3):

A Lesser [Metamagic Rod of Quickening](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods/metamagic-quicken/) can do this for you, up to three times a day, at a price of 35 000 gold.